# Show app on top of PhoneGap BarcodeScanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I'm looking to integrate PhoneGap's BarcodeScanner plugin with my app but would like to integrate it with the existing HTML/JS (inside the WebView) a little more closely than it currently allows.

Ideally I would like to see the BarcodeScanner's 'camera capture' view appear *underneath* PhoneGap's main WebView so I can layer my app's controls on top (toolbar etc).

I have come across a similar plugin from Moodstocks (http://www.moodstocks.com/2013/04/03/augmented-reality-with-phonegap-sencha-touch/) which appears to do just this by giving the WebView a transparent background and displaying it above the camera's view. The source code for this plugin can be found here (https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-plugin) and more specifically (based on my reading the code with very unknowledgable eyes!) on Line 74-80 of the MSScannerController.m (https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-plugin/blob/master/ios/MSScannerController.m).

So my question is, firstly, is this achievable? and, secondly, how can I modify the PhoneGap plugin to do it?

Any pointers or direction would be very helpful!

Comment: Did you ever get this working with the PhoneGap BarcodeScanner plugin? I would love to see the source code!

Comment: I didn't get it working with the "official" scanner plugin but I was able to use the Moodstocks one (for free as I was just using the scanning part and not the serverside lookup APIs etc) and it works very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is quite sure - YES.

For the second question, what we (I work for Moodstocks) have done is:

- Detaching the webview from `MainViewController`, knowing that you can retrieve the webview via plugin. In [MoodstocksPlugin.m, lines 99-100](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-plugin/blob/2a90bbbc0a3ef6dcef562b32037a588bdaccb94d/ios/MoodstocksPlugin.m#L99-L100) show how we pass the plugin's reference:
- Attaching the webview to the current view controller, which is our scanner controller. [MSScannerController.m, Line 46](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-plugin/blob/2a90bbbc0a3ef6dcef562b32037a588bdaccb94d/ios/MSScannerController.m#L46) shows how we take the webview over:

I hope this can give you several ideas about how to modify the original PhoneGap BarcodeScanner plugin, just out of curious, why not use MoodstocksPlugin directly? ;)

p.s Here is a [video](http://www.moodstocks.com/2013/04/12/moodstocks-on-device-image-recognition-phonegap-plugin-sencha-touch-demo/) shows the animation of our [Sencha Touch demo](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-sencha-demo-app) made with our plugin.

Comment: Thanks very much for you're answer! Great to hear from someone who's done it! With regards to using the MoodstocksPlugin directly, that would be ideal, but I was under the impression that I would have to use your 'lookup service' as well? Maybe I've misread things so your clarification would be appreciated! :)

Comment: You can use Moodstocks SDK for barcode scan without using our image recognition. It is controlled by a scan option variable that you can easily modify. To kick off, you just need to register on [our developer platform](https://developers.moodstocks.com/) to get a pair of api key & secret for you application. Then you will receive weekly report for your application's scan statistics! :)

Comment: Thanks Qian, I gave it a bash yesterday and got it all integrated nicely with my iOS app (will try Android shortly). Are there any docs for the JS functions that must be called? I couldn't find any anywhere and so just made best guesses based on the sample code. Also, having all the integration instructions split over multiple repos' readmes was a bit confusing and hard to find - would be better if they were all in your help centre (maybe they are and I just didn't see them?). Otherwise, thanks a lot and great work! :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback! The help docs for PhoneGap plugin are currently only available on Github. We'll see what we can do to improve our support! Looking forward to see you app! :)